# How to pass in prop from react-router / url to graphql query?

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo, apollo-client

If I have a route like this:

```
<Route path="/something/:id" component={Something} />
```

And I have a query like this

```
const somethingQuery = gql`query getSomething {
  something(id:1) {
    name
  }
}`

export default compose(
  graphql(somethingQuery),
)(Something)
```

Right now this always pulls `something` with the `id` of `1`.

How do I pass in the url parameter `:id` to the query `id`?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you need to use an arrow function for the options

```
const somethingQuery = gql`query getSomething {
  something(id:$id) {
    name
  }
}`

const somethingWithData = graphql(somethingQuery, {
  options: (ownProps) => {
    variables: {
      id: ownProps.params.id
    }
  }
})(Something)

export default somethingWithData
```

Also, for me the params are found in props.match so it will look like this (in React Router 4). Oh, and I also pass the `($id: ID!)` argument to the query

```
const somethingQuery = gql`query getSomething($id: ID!) {
  something(id:$id) {
    name
  }
}`

const somethingWithData = graphql(somethingQuery, {
  options: (ownProps) => {
    variables: {
      id: ownProps.match.params.id
    }
  }
})(Something)

export default somethingWithData
```

Comment: Should be the accepted answer, fixed it for me! And great with the note about react router 4.

Answer (score 0):

To introduce a variable for the id, you should use the GraphQL notation for query variables. First add the $id argument to the query parameters and assign it to the id argument

```
const somethingQuery = gql`query getSomething {
  something(id:$id) {
    name
  }
}`

const somethingWithData = graphql(somethingQuery, {
  options: (ownProps) {
    variables: {
      id: ownProps.params.id
    }
  }
})(Something)

export default somethingWithData
```

You can also use compose in export like you did in your example, but I like it this way ;)

Comment: Need to use an arrow function for options, see my answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/45336215/582309